# Switching content of 2 UIWebViews

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview, copy

In my app i have a scrollView which contains several webviews (im doing something like infinite scroll using only 3 webViews) ... In order to do that i need to switch content of 2 web views (something like copy one webview into another maybe?)...this can't be done with just loading the htmlString from one webView into another...

any ideas? thanks a lot in advance

EDIT : The code is very similar to this tutorial : http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html

Comment: Do you have any code for something you tried? Why can't it be done by loading the htmlString from one into another?

Comment: i added some reference to my code...check out pposthoorn's comment on that page - he explains why this cant be done just by loading html string - the page really flashes ...

Comment: I got the same problem on infinite webview. Have you solve the problem? How to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone cares i've solved it just by adding uiwebvies into a mutable array and then by switching them first in scroll view (visibily) and just after that switching them in that mutable array (logically). In example from the link above the code would look like this for "scrolling right" (in scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:) :

```
         CGRect frame = ((UIView*)[self.arrWebViewsContent objectAtIndex:2]).frame;
        ((UIView*)[self.arrWebViewsContent objectAtIndex:2]).frame = ((UIView*)[self.arrWebViewsContent objectAtIndex:1]).frame;
        ((UIView*)[self.arrWebViewsContent objectAtIndex:1]).frame = ((UIView*)[self.arrWebViewsContent objectAtIndex:0]).frame;
        ((UIView*)[self.arrWebViewsContent objectAtIndex:0]).frame = frame;

        UIView *view_tmp = [self.arrWebViewsContent objectAtIndex:0];
        [self.arrWebViewsContent replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[self.arrWebViewsContent objectAtIndex:1]];
        [self.arrWebViewsContent replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:[self.arrWebViewsContent objectAtIndex:2]];
        [self.arrWebViewsContent replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject:view_tmp];
```

Comment: can you give more sample code on your success? Thanks.